# I want to create a Jbutton in netbeans environment which backs up a mysql database with all its contents in it

Tags: xampp, ubuntu-14.04, netbeans-8

I am not very experienced with Java programming, and i am trying to create a `Jbutton` using netbeans to backup a database. I am using Xampp and am using Ubuntu 14.04.I have been googling for a week now and even applied some of the answers i found on stackoverflow here but the button is not backing up, the programme executes well but when a i press the button for backing up the database, the process never stops executing and i even trying to leave to execute for 12 hrs but still it didnot work. 
Below is the method am executing of the `JButton`, please any one who know how to do this can you help me.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String dbName="Erikom";
        String dbUser="root";
        String dbPass="";

        String executeCmd="";
        executeCmd="/opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u "+dbUser+" -p "+dbPass+" "+dbName+" -r /home/maron/backup.sql";

        try {
            Process runtimeProcess =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete=runtimeProcess.waitFor();
            if(processComplete==0){
                System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Could not take backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this command outside of Java? It looks like your password is blank, so it's also probably trying to use the `dbName` as the password...

Comment: i Had not run this command out of java but i got that command from one of the stack over flow pages and gave it parameters